# getting an java arithmeticException error

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

Can someone please help to tell why I'm getting zero in my arithmetic operations?
I'm trying to solve this arithmetic problem which gives value of x and y but it's giving me java.lang.arithmeticException error or showing zero result.
It will be really helpful to me.

this is my input
a=6,b=10,c=8,d=12,e=800,f=900

**This linear equation to obtain the values for x and y can be solved using

x    = (ed -fb)/(ad -bc),    y = (fa -ec)/(ad – bc)**

this is the problem that i'm trying to solve.

````
public class linearequation {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in);
        linear lin1 = new linear(scn.nextInt(),scn.nextInt(),scn.nextInt(),scn.nextInt(),scn.nextInt(),scn.nextInt());
        if(lin1.isSolvable()) {
            System.out.println(lin1.getx());
            System.out.println(lin1.gety());
        }else {
            System.out.println("No Solution");
        }
    }
}
class linear {
    private int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    int x, y;
    int den = ((a * d) - (b * c));

    public linear(int na, int nb, int nc, int nd, int ne, int nf) {
        na = a;
        nb = b;
        nc = c;
        nd = d;
        ne = e;
        nf = f;

    }

    public int geta() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getb() {
        return b;
    }

    public int getc() {
        return c;
    }

    public int getd() {
        return d;
    }

    public int gete() {
        return e;
    }

    public int getf() {
        return f;
    }

    public int getx() {
        return x = ((e * d) - (f * b)) / den;
    }

    public int gety() {
        return y = ((f * a) - (e * c)) / den;
    }


    public boolean isSolvable() {

        if (den <= 0) {
            return false;
        } else {

            return true;
        }
    }

}```
````

Comment: ArithmeticException  means you try to divide by zero. Right ?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? I think you are trying to divide by 0.

Comment: `den` is predefined to be 0 since it is calculated before the constructor can assign values to a, b, c, d, e, and f. You need to set it after assigning the values in the constructor.

Comment: no no my input is a=6,b=10,c=8,d=12,e=800,f=900 @g.momo

Comment: my input is a=6,b=10,c=8,d=12,e=800,f=900 @tibetiroka

Comment: @ZeeshanHaider, the error is caused by dividing by 0.  While the inputs are retrieved correctly, `den` is not updated to use them.

Comment: @Locke if i don't use den and just use ((e * d) - (f * b)) / ((a * d) - (b * c)) in getx and gety it willl give the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see your constructor for `linear` is the problem.

You're passing `na, nb, nc, nd, ne, nf` into it and reassign them to be the value of `a, b, c, d, e, and f`, respectively, when you actually want to assign the other way around, e.g. `a = na` instead of `na = a`.

Also, you're setting `den` before the values for `a...f` are set by way of the constructor. `den` is never reassigned and thus stays `0`.

This is what your constructor should look like:

```java
public linear(int na, int nb, int nc, int nd, int ne, int nf) {
    a = na;
    b = nb;
    c = nc;
    d = nd;
    e = ne;
    f = nf;
    
    den = ((a * d) - (b * c));
}
```

Comment: brother if i put den in constructor then is there any way to use the same den in getx?

Comment: You'll have to define ```den``` as an instance field to the class ```linear```. You've implicitly done this in your provided code example by this line: ```int den = ((a * d) - (b * c));```. Reduce this line to be ```int den;``` and you'll have yourself a field ```den``` on your class ```linear``` which can be used in the class' instances.